# Draw a long arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

how to add the word "time" to this arrow? This is my code. Many thanks.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
            > = Straight Barb,
node distance = 28mm and 44mm,
    BC/.style = {
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, 
                    raise=3pt, amplitude=6pt},
                    very thick, pen colour={black}
                },
   dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt},
every label/.append style = {align=left},
font= \linespread{1}\selectfont
                    ]
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (13,0);
\node (a) [dot,label=below:some\\text here.] at (2.2,0) {};
\node (b) [dot,label=below:some\\text here.,
           right=of a] {};
\node (c) [dot,label=below:some\\text here.,
           right=of b] {};
\draw[->]  (a) -- ++ (0,0.5) node [above] {\emph{t} = 0};           
\draw[->]  (b) -- ++ (0,0.5) node[above] {\emph{t} = 1};
\draw[->]  (c) -- ++ (0,0.5) node[above] {\emph{t} = 2};           
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
```

I want this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `node[right] {Time}` to the end of the `\draw` path for the long arrow.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
            > = Straight Barb,
node distance = 28mm and 44mm,
   dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt},
every label/.append style = {align=left},
font= \linespread{1}\selectfont
                    ]
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (13,0) node[right] {Time};
\node (a) [dot,label=below:some\\text here.] at (2.2,0) {};
\node (b) [dot,label=below:some\\text here.,
           right=of a] {};
\node (c) [dot,label=below:some\\text here.,
           right=of b] {};
\draw[->]  (a) -- ++ (0,0.5) node[above] {\emph{t} = 0};           
\draw[->]  (b) -- ++ (0,0.5) node[above] {\emph{t} = 1};
\draw[->]  (c) -- ++ (0,0.5) node[above] {\emph{t} = 2};           
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. Problem solved.

Comment: You had this already for the other nodes. =) And Steven and I posted the same solution at almost the same time. So, it is up to you whose answer you finally accept ...

Answer (score 4):

Just add a node `\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (13,0) node [right] {$t$};` to the end of the arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
%            > = Straight Barb,
node distance = 28mm and 44mm,
    BC/.style = {
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, 
                    raise=3pt, amplitude=6pt},
                    very thick, pen colour={black}
                },
   dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt},
every label/.append style = {align=left},
font= \linespread{1}\selectfont
                    ]
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (13,0) node [right] {$t$};
\node (a) [dot,label=below:some\\text here.] at (2.2,0) {};
\node (b) [dot,label=below:some\\text here.,
           right=of a] {};
\node (c) [dot,label=below:some\\text here.,
           right=of b] {};
\draw[->]  (a) -- ++ (0,0.5) node [above] {\emph{t} = 0};           
\draw[->]  (b) -- ++ (0,0.5) node[above] {\emph{t} = 1};
\draw[->]  (c) -- ++ (0,0.5) node[above] {\emph{t} = 2};           
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. Problem solved.